# aws appsync auth directive not limiting access as expected

Tags: aws-appsync

In my graphQl schema for the appsync api I am using I want to limit my users actions based on the group they belong to.

According to the docs, adding the line `aws_auth(cognito_groups: ["Admins"])` should restrict access to only users belonging to the group of "Admins". This does not happen when I run the mutation from the appsync console or from the app itself.

My mutation is as follows:

```
type Mutation @aws_iam
@aws_cognito_user_pools {
    createItem(input: CreateItemInput!): Item
    updateItem(input: UpdateItemInput!): Item
    @aws_auth(cognito_groups: ["Admins"])
}
```

The @aws_iam and @aws_cognito_user_pools directives seem to work fine. 
But anyone that has authenticated or has an iam role, can still perform an update, even if they do not belong to the "Admins" group.

What is going on here? Is there additional configuration that needs to be done to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you should avoid using `@aws_auth` at the same time as `@aws_cognito_user_pools` & `aws_iam` as they have slightly different behavior ([see docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/security.html#using-additional-authorization-modes)).

If you want to restrict access to `updateItem` while still allowing any IAM auth'd user to `createItem` then you can use:

```
type Mutation {
    createItem(input: CreateItemInput!): Item
      @aws_iam
    updateItem(input: UpdateItemInput!): Item
      @aws_cognito_user_pools(cognito_groups: ["Admins"])
}
```

Placing the directive on the type implies that the auth config is valid for all the fields in that type. Placing the directive on the field makes it apply to the field only.

Answer (score 5):

Just to clarify further as this is not well documented.

If you are using a single authorization provider and that provider is Cognito, you should always use the `@aws_auth` directive.  Do not use the `@aws_cognito_user_pools` directive as it does not work if you are using group-based authorization.  This is not well documented in the AWS Cognito docs and is a trap as AppSync will allow you to configure this directive.

If you are using multiple authorization providers and you are using Cognito, you must use the `@aws_cognito_user_pools` directive as documented in the AWS Cognito docs.  Strangely group-based authorization works correctly using `@aws_cognito_user_pools` but ONLY when using multiple authorization providers.

Comment: "You can’t use the aws_auth directive along with additional authorization modes. aws_auth works only in the context of AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS authorization with no additional authorization modes. However, you can use the aws_cognito_user_pools directive in place of the @aws_auth directive, using the same arguments. The main difference between the two is that you can specify aws_cognito_user_pools on any field and object type definitions."